# How to create file when path is 256 char long in Windows 8 application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

how to create file when path is 256 char long in Windows 8 application .

When try to create file with 256 char path ..no error coming and no file created.

```
//------------------

 string fileName = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.txt";

ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName);

//------------------
```

Comment: Thats cause u use async, you should also listen for callback

Comment: Did you tries file.append or file.create()

Comment: This method and assembly we are using in Web and Windows application not Windows 8 App . I already faced this problem in Web application so i used "Delimon.Win32.IO"  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-17cc7893